# What do I need to do so that Json.Net to behaves as if the [Serializable] attribute isn't there?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I've got a problem where a web client application is failing to de-serialize a JSON message correctly. The bug was caused when the type which represents the message got marked as [Serializable].

Below is some code which reproduces the problem. It needs Newtonsoft.Json, and Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client NuGet packages.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            String cargo = "Hello";

            SerializableType serializableTypeOriginal = new SerializableType(cargo);
            String jsonFromSerializableType = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serializableTypeOriginal);

            NonSerializableType nonSerializableTypeOriginalNonSerializableType = new NonSerializableType(cargo);
            String jsonFromNonSerializableType = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nonSerializableTypeOriginalNonSerializableType);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(jsonFromSerializableType == jsonFromNonSerializableType);

            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonFromSerializableType, new UTF8Encoding(), "application/json");
            SerializableType serializableTypeFromSerializableType = httpContent.ReadAsAsync<SerializableType>().Result;
            //serializableTypeFromSerializableType.A == null ✘

            httpContent = new StringContent(jsonFromSerializableType, new UTF8Encoding(), "application/json");
            NonSerializableType nonSerializableTypeFromSerializableType = httpContent.ReadAsAsync<NonSerializableType>().Result;
            //nonSerializableTypeFromSerializableType.A == "Hello" ✔

            httpContent = new StringContent(jsonFromNonSerializableType, new UTF8Encoding(), "application/json");
            SerializableType serializableTypeFromNonSerializableType = httpContent.ReadAsAsync<SerializableType>().Result;
            //serializableTypeFromNonSerializableType.A == null ✘

            httpContent = new StringContent(jsonFromNonSerializableType, new UTF8Encoding(), "application/json");
            NonSerializableType nonSerializableTypeFromNonSerializableType = httpContent.ReadAsAsync<NonSerializableType>().Result;
            //nonSerializableTypeFromNonSerializableType.A == "Hello" ✔
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class SerializableType
    {
        private readonly string _a;

        public SerializableType(String a)
        {
            _a = a;
        }

        public string A
        {
            get { return _a; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("A: {0}", A);
        }
    }

    public class NonSerializableType
    {
        private readonly string _a;

        public NonSerializableType(String a)
        {
            _a = a;
        }

        public string A
        {
            get { return _a; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("A: {0}", A);
        }
    }    
}
```

Here's the NuGet packages file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

It seems to me that for classes not decorated with the [Serializable] attribute then JSON.Net will use the constructor injection to hydrate the class on de-serialization. But when the [Serialization] attribute is present I can't work out what to do?

Can I have the [Serialization] attribute, and make JSON.Net use the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control source code for the type that is marked as `[Serializable]`, another solution is to add a `[JsonObject]` attribute to the class:

```
    [Serializable]
    [JsonObject]
    public class SerializableType
    {
        ...
    }
```

Then re-run the tests from the original question and you should get "Hello" for all four.

Comment: +1: This is a much better solution than the one I worked out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a solution:

There is an override of ReadAsAsync (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh943959(v=vs.118).aspx) which allows you to specify the MediaTypeFormatter to use explicitly.

You can instruct the JsonMediaTypeFormatter to ignore the [Serializable] attribute, by changing the property IgnoreSerializationAttribute on the "DefaultContractResolver" (http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationAttributes.htm).

Putting the pieces together:

```
private static void Main()
    {
        JsonMediaTypeFormatter mediaTypeFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

        mediaTypeFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
        {
            IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true
        };

        String cargo = "Hello";

        SerializableType serializableTypeOriginal = new SerializableType(cargo);
        String jsonFromSerializableType = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serializableTypeOriginal);

        NonSerializableType nonSerializableTypeOriginalNonSerializableType = new NonSerializableType(cargo);
        String jsonFromNonSerializableType = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nonSerializableTypeOriginalNonSerializableType);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(jsonFromSerializableType == jsonFromNonSerializableType);

        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonFromSerializableType, new UTF8Encoding(), "application/json");
        SerializableType serializableTypeFromSerializableType = httpContent.ReadAsAsync<SerializableType>(new[] { mediaTypeFormatter }).Result;
        //serializableTypeFromSerializableType.A == "Hello" ✔

        httpContent = new StringContent(jsonFromSerializableType, new UTF8Encoding(), "application/json");
        NonSerializableType nonSerializableTypeFromSerializableType = httpContent.ReadAsAsync<NonSerializableType>(new[] { mediaTypeFormatter }).Result;
        //nonSerializableTypeFromSerializableType.A == "Hello" ✔

        httpContent = new StringContent(jsonFromNonSerializableType, new UTF8Encoding(), "application/json");
        SerializableType serializableTypeFromNonSerializableType = httpContent.ReadAsAsync<SerializableType>(new[] { mediaTypeFormatter }).Result;
        //serializableTypeFromNonSerializableType.A == "Hello" ✔

        httpContent = new StringContent(jsonFromNonSerializableType, new UTF8Encoding(), "application/json");
        NonSerializableType nonSerializableTypeFromNonSerializableType = httpContent.ReadAsAsync<NonSerializableType>(new[] { mediaTypeFormatter }).Result;
        //nonSerializableTypeFromNonSerializableType.A == "Hello" ✔

    }
```